# Accessing session vars outside the directory they were created in

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-cookies

I have never ran into this problem before and I have been trying to troubleshoot this for quite a while now.

I am setting my session variables on the `main.php` page and when I do a `var_dump()` on a page in the root directory (note the paths), it prints out an empty array.

It seems to only pick up the session variables within the same directory they are created in. However, I need to access session vars in at least the two directories mentioned below. Is this possible? I appreciate any suggestions on how to accomplish this.

It is important that the changes I make to the session variables in one directory reflect in the other (i.e. unset, update value, etc.).

**Edit:** All sessions are started in the same parent directory, the only problem is many session variables are created in the sub-directory and then need to be accessed in the parent (root) directory.

Many thanks in advance!

actions/search/main.php

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['id'] = 22;
$_SESSION['name'] = 'Bob';
```

manageajax.php

```
session_start();

if(isset($_GET['handleSess']) && $_GET['handleSess']==1){
   //do stuff with session vars
   var_dump($_SESSION); // output array(0) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, you have to set the sessions/cookies in the root of your domain (mydomain.com/)so you can access them from any location in your root path. in what path (or file) do you start the session ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't really understand your answer. It is more suitable as a comment. See my original post, all sessions are started in the same parent directory, the only problem is many session variables are created in the sub-directory and then need to be accessed in the parent (root) directory. Can you please show my an example of the code to solve this?

Comment: The ones that you create in the sub directories need to be created in the root if you would like to access them from the root ! or better, you start the session in index (or root) then you add variables to it, don't create other session if this is not required.

Comment: This does not work. I am working on a very large application, I cannot access where session's are being started or prevent multiple sessions from being created. I was looking into your first suggestion but you deleted it...

Comment: I did because i am not sure how you are handling the session management , if you can explain a bit more it will be easy to suggest a suitable solution.

Comment: ** All sessions are started in the same parent directory, the only problem is some session variables are created in the sub-directory and then need to be accessed in the parent (root) directory.**

Comment: first of all, are you sure that you are getting the right session ? where do you store the session id ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40203/discussion-between-anchovylegend-and-e-nouri)